# Stinger Filter vs parameter Validation Filter

Tags: java, validation, security, filter, owasp

I am a newbie to java security, I need to implement input validator to my project , we are using struts 2.5.13 and we are testing through contrast security tool.

We had one vulnerability shown by contrast tool and that is “Expression Language Injection” and During my research on Owasp website , I have seen two projects one is **Stinger Filter** and Other **Parameter Validation Filter** . I am confused and not being able to decide which one is better and could provide more protection to my application.

Any of the  security experts can answer this, I would like to know the thought on both the projects and which one I should use and why you think that’s better.

I will be thankful to you , if you provide me some detailed insight and help me in understanding security principles.

Comment: Security experts might be here https://security.stackexchange.com/... I think your question might be considered too broad in this place.

Comment: If you are trying to secure your site, asking questions of strangers on the internet is probably not the correct approach. Hire an expert.

Answer (score 0):

Both Stinger and PVF are ancient. I wouldn't use either. Fortunately, you don't need validation. You need to prevent untrusted input (like an HTTP parameter) from getting into an Expression Engine.  So look at the full stack that Contrast gives you. Find where in your code is making that happen. Then fix it.  Unfortunately, the problem may not be in your code, it may be in Struts itself. In that case, you should upgrade to the latest version. If that doesn't fix the problem, then you've discovered a new vulnerability in Struts -- fame and fortune await. Or you can just turn on Contrast Protect to prevent all EL vulnerabilities from being exploited.